# Change a theme based on the URL

Tags: php, drupal-7

I have a Drupal7 instance example.com.Which has a theme bartik installed and activated.

I want to have a different theme to be shown whenever a page under this section is viewed (e.g. http://example.com/events, http://example.com/node/1). How do I do that?Is their any shot code or  drupal modules are available to show different themes based on url?

Comment: Do you really want to use different theme or just a different template for different page?

Comment: I want a different theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Drupal module: [ThemeKey](https://www.drupal.org/project/themekey)

> ThemeKey allows you to define simple or sophisticated theme-switching rules which allow automatic selection of a theme depending on current path, taxonomy terms, language, node-type, and many, many other properties.

Or, you can use theme callback. Here is a [doc](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7.x)